# How to connect MongoDB to Ani Meteor Theme?

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor

I am using the following [Ani Meteor Theme](https://startmeteorjs.com/themes/ani-meteor-theme/) and I can't seem to connect my MongoDB successfully.

I tried to create `package.json` and add the following (didn't work):

```
{
    "galaxy.meteor.com": { 
     "env": { 
       "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://..." 
     }
   }
 }
```

I noticed `packages` file inside `.meteor` which lists the packaged in the project but the structure is different from `package.json`.

My question is, how can I connect my mongoDB database using [Anti Meteor Theme](https://startmeteorjs.com/themes/ani-meteor-theme/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the server:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    process.env.MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://...';
});
```